# Inline operator!= undefined reference

Tags: c++

I am getting the compiler error `undefined reference to` when attempting to inline `operator!=` as a friend function.

Here is an example:

```
// color.hpp
class Color
{
    friend bool operator==(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs);
    inline friend bool operator!=(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs);
};

// color.cpp
bool operator==(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs)
{
}

inline bool operator!=(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs)
{
}
```

I cannot implement the operators in the header file, as this creates multiple definition errors.

I am compiling with `--std=c++11`, g++ 5.2.

Comment: does this work if you remove `inline` when declaring the friend function?

Comment: No, this doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `inline` from the class definition.

After the class definition, in the header file, add the following:

```
inline bool
operator!=(const Color& lhs, const Color& rhs)
{
  return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Remove the definition in the source file.

Comment: That seems to compile, except that I get multiple definition errors on `operator==` which is not declared using `inline`

Comment: Moved `operator==` back to the `.cpp` file, and it works, why?!

Comment: Why wouldn't you implement these operators as friend?

Comment: I don't see a need to make them as `friend`s when they can be implemented as direct members (using only one operand).  Maybe it's a style thing.  See also *Efficient C++*, *More Efficient C++* by Scott Meyers.